Empty file created on upload by springboot/tomcat
We are using spring boot 2.3 for a simple web application which exposes a rest service to allow the user upload a file.
Rest service signature is like
    @PostMapping(value = "/fileVerification", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public String fileVerification(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
          ...
        }

This web application runs in a stand alone apache tomcat 9.0 (we are not using the embedded one in spring boot).
This is the set of configuration we are using;
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
I noticed the following I cannot explain much:

When I upload a file it is stored into java.io.tmp dir, which is fine but the strange thing it is the file empty. I set a breakpoint in remote debug just after the rest service is triggered and even there the file is empty even if the file is bigger than 2kb. I should have the file stored there, isn't it ?

In the java.io.tmp dir there are also directories created "crl" and "out" which are always empty. What are they used for ?

I would expect file is deleted but it seems file is just emptied and then deleted on server restart.


Probably is related to the servlet container (tomcat 9) but it would be great to have some enlightenment.

As a test, try setting this configuration: spring.servlet.multipart.location Doc reference here, search for it.

@JorgeCampos thanks but I did not ask how to change but why files are stored empty (as well as other questions).

I did not say this was a solution, rather a test to eliminate possibilities. Good luck with your problem.

it set as default when JVM want to write temp value from TMP  into system. If you delete it, it  will generate new each times. It is empty because nothing was saved down to your server. That s all
